# Protractor html navigation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, protractor

I have a protractor test retrieving an element based on a repeater. I need to navigate inside this element and verify several values on several elements contained in it. I could do a series of call with the webdriver (protractor) but then I would have to chain the promises.

What I want to do instead is get this element, extract the html and then navigate into it without calling again the webdriver. For now I managed to extract the innerHtml but that's a string and thus not suitable for navigation. I could use jquery's parseHTML but it would force me to include jquery just for that...

Is there no out of the box way included in protractor to avoid calling again and again the webdriver ?

Here is what I have for now with `basketLines` being a repeater locator :

```
this.getBasketLines = function () {
        return basketLines.map(function (lineElement) {
            return lineElement.getInnerHtml();
        }).then(function (innerHtmls) {
            console.log('What to do to navigate in the html ?');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody seem to know a better way than calling several time webdriver I at least did it in the shortest way I could. That's what I obtained, if anyone has another suggestion I would love to hear about it :

```
this.getLinesInfo = function () {
        return element.all(by.name('productName')).map(function (elts) {
            return elts.getText();
        }).then(function (productNames) {
            return element.all(by.name('productPrice')).map(function (elts) {
                return elts.getText();
            }).then(function (productPrices) {
                return element.all(by.name('productQuantity')).map(function (elts) {
                    return elts.getText();
                }).then(function (productQuantities) {
                    return element.all(by.name('linePrice')).map(function (elts) {
                        return elts.getText();
                    }).then(function (linePrices) {
                        var linesInfo = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < productNames.length; i++) {
                            linesInfo.push({
                                name:       productNames[i],
                                price:      productPrices[i],
                                quantity:   productQuantities[i],
                                total:      linePrices[i]
                            });
                        }
                        return linesInfo;
                    });});});
        });
    };
```